# Certification failed for background audio streaming app

Tags: microsoft-metro, audio-streaming, windows-store-apps

I submitted a background audio app for certification and has failed with two reasons in which I could not figure out why.

Reason 1:

> This app failed to correctly respond to at least one of the play,
>   pause, or play/pause events.

I understand that the `MediaControl` events for `Play`, `Pause`, `Stop` and `PlayPause` need to be catered, and have done so (and tested on both tablets and local devices that they are working) in the code. However, due to the reason that stopping a media stream and restarting it requires a longer-than-expected time, I used `MediaElement.Pause()` for both "Pause" and "Stop".

I read [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907731/allowing-suspension-of-a-windows-store-app-when-audio-is-paused) who had similar problem at the certification phase. Somebody recommended to use `MediaElement.PlaybackRate = 0;` instead. However, this is not ideal for long pauses as the stream will not move on.

What I wish to know is am I doing this the right way? For all my `MediaControl` events I have made sure that the `MediaControl.IsPlaying` property is correctly set as well.

Also, another reason it failed was this:

> App failed the Perf test in the Windows ACK. See the following links
>   for more information: Test cases ran:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh920274.aspx

I have ran my app against the ACK and it all passed. The only thing I can think of is that the app does not enter `suspend mode` when the hardware (or on-screen) media control pause button is pressed. I have placed a debugger in the `App_Suspending` event but it never hits there.

As the description is too vague I am not sure if this is the problem. But if it's the case, can I know how do I force the app to enter suspended mode? I tried looking in the `Window.Current` class and `Application.Current` class, but to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After nearly 10 attempts in releasing the app, I finally got to the root of the problem, thanks to some guessing work by the folks at Microsoft too.

My app will automatically start the `MediaElement` streaming after the app is started. The background-capable audio will prevent the app from passing WACK because it will never enter suspended mode!

So, in order to get pass the store's WACK I had to remove the auto-starting feature, and now the app is in the store! (Phew).

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue be sure that your media element is ready to play using :

```
while (CurrentTrack.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Opening || CurrentTrack.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Buffering)
{
   await Task.Delay(100);
}

CurrentTrack.Play();
```

Also you have to stop your media element when the view is unload.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the streaming audio was checked and marked as ready to play after the `MediaElement_MediaOpened` event is triggered. I also figured out that the app will not enter suspended mode as long as the debugger is attached. It seems that it is a requirement from the app store that all media resources be released when the app enters suspended mode (even for a background audio-capable app), I have since solved the problem by releasing the streaming source. Thanks!